# Integrate cua-mode with evil-insert-state

Tags: key-bindings, evil, cua-mode

I'm starting to think that using the regular <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> keys for kill-ring operations make sense, as they're used that way in every other program I use regularly. (And I'm starting to develop conflicting muscle memories.) However, I use `evil-mode`. Is there a way to integrate `cua-mode` (with keys) and `evil-insert-state`?

Comment: I'd recommend to set F2 F3 F4 for that. It's easy to do, and no key conflict, and easier on hand too. But, if you use evil, vi has easy keys for copy/paste, why'd you want the standard shortcut with control?

Comment: @XahLee If my goal is compatibility, then `F2` and co. do me no favors (although they may be great for other people). While I do use `vim` style bindings for much of my pasting, I do access and manipulate the kill ring in `insert` state as well. `C-v` is faster than `ESC p i` or even `jj p i`. Earlier, I had no trouble with `C-w` and co. but recently I've had to use domain specific editors for my job, and now my muscles are confused. I think consistency may end up being better, although I'm not entirely sure, as I can't test.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit late to the party but I use the following:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-c") 'cua-copy-region)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-v") 'cua-paste)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-x") 'cua-cut-region)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'undo-tree-undo)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-y") 'undo-tree-redo)
```

This also includes undo and redo for `C-z` and `C-y` and requires the `undo-tree` package. Keep in mind that if you want to use the usual Emacs shortcuts like `C-x C-c` to quit Emacs you'll need to leave `Insert State` first.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to do the normal thing where `C-x C-c` and `C-x` are disambiguated using timers (or any of the other methods `cua-mode` uses in a regular Emacs setup).

Comment: I'll look into it