# Cua-mode commands broken at launch (when using evil), until the mode is manually toggled

Tags: evil, cua-mode

I'm very new to emacs, and can't seem to get cua-mode to work by default. I'm using emacs 26.3 with spacemacs 0.300 on Kubuntu 20.04.1

I have set `(cua-mode t)` in my `.spacemacs`, and cua-mode shows up as active when I check the `M-x menu`, but the cua commands won't work *until* I toggle cua-mode in the `M-x menu` (i.e. turn it off, and then on again), then they work perfectly.

This gets old, and I would really like to have those commands working by default.

I've tried adjusting a few settings to no avail, here are the related lines in my `.spacemacs` now:

```lisp
    (cua-mode t)
    (setq cua-auto-tabify-rectangles nil) ;; Don't tabify after rectangle commands
    (transient-mark-mode 1) ;; No region when it is not highlighted
    (setq cua-keep-region-after-copy t) ;; Standard behaviour
    (setq org-CUA-compatible t)
```

Thanks for reading, any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So, fwiw, I belatedly discovered that I can remap the commands to accomplish the same effect, as [described here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29165/31113), by adding the following to my `init.el`:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-c") 'cua-copy-region)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-v") 'cua-paste)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-x") 'cua-cut-region)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'undo-tree-undo)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-y") 'undo-tree-redo)
```